# How to split array values and make separate array

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the code to store email and phone in separate array How to do that i am facing a problem to store phone and email in separate array after spliting single word using split function

in the below coding the phone numbers printing three times

```
 public class SplitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = { "9964289813-pradeep@­gmail.com", "9591237001-pramod@g­mail.com",
            "8722922982-nandi@gm­ail.com" };
    String[] temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        String singleWord = s1[i];
        String[] splitArray = singleWord.split("-");
        String[] temp1 = new String[s1.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < temp1.length; j++) {
            temp1[j] = splitArray[0];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < temp1.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(temp1[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *i am facing a problem after spliting single word using split function* ==> What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

create two separate array (one Long [] for storing integer values and 2nd String[] for email values) with initializing both

```
long numArray = new long[s1.length];
String emailArray = new String[s1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {            
    String[] parts = s1[i].split("-");
    numArray[i] = Long.parseLong(parts[0]);  
    emailArray[i] = parts[1];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer arraylist
try this out

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SplitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = { "9964289813-pradeep@gmail.com", "9591237001-pramod@gmail.com", "8722922982-nandi@gmail.com" };
ArrayList<String> numberlList= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> emailList= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        String singleWord = s1[i];
numberlList.add(singleWord.substring(0, singleWord.indexOf("-")));
emailList.add(singleWord.substring(singleWord.indexOf("-")));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 String arrays, one for phones, second for emails. Size of both will be s1.length.

In for loop, add extracted phone to phone array and extracted email to email array:

```
String[] s1 = { "9964289813-pradeep@gmail.com","9591237001pramod@gmail.com","8722922982-nandi@gmail.com" };

String[] phones = new String[s1.length];
String[] emails = new String[s1.length];

for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    String singleWord = s1[i];
    String[] words = singleWord.split("-");
    phones[i] = words[0];
    emails[i] = words[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
public class SplitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = { "9964289813-pradeep@gmail.com", "9591237001-pramod@gmail.com", "8722922982-nandi@gmail.com" };
    String[] phoneArr = new String[s1.length];
    String[] emailArr = new String[s1.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        String[] splitArray = s1[i].split("-");
        phoneArr[i] = splitArray[0];
        emailArr[i] = splitArray[1];
    }

    // "phoneArr" will contain all Phone Numbers
    // "emailArr" will contain all Email IDs

}
```

}